# How to manage realm instance?

Tags: android, realm

I have an Activity that manage multiples fragments and nested fragment, like that :

Activity -> RootFragment1 -> NestedFragment1, NestedFragment2 
             -> RootFragment2 -> NestedFragment3, NestedFragment4
...

I use to get a realm instance and close it in each nested fragment in onStart, onStop methods but sometimes I meet this exception :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance
>   has already been closed, making it unusable.

Is there a recommended way to get a Realm instance and close it ? In my case should I get an instance in Activity and pass it through my fragments ?

Comment: Personally I'd consider moving them to `onCreate/onDestroy` of fragments

Comment: Although **actually** I keep a single Realm instance open for the UI thread and manage it with retained fragments, but that's a bit tricky to explain :D it avoids all this tricky lifecycle shenanigan

Comment: Do you have a sample of your solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say that you should open/close Realm in `onCreateView()/onDestroyView()`, but in my experience the fragment lifecycle is unusually erratic, so I can show you two other approaches.

1.) open/close the Realm in `Activity.onCreate()` and `Activity.onDestroy()`, then share it to the fragments (and even down the view hierarchy!) using `getSystemService()`.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // ...
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
        // ...
    }

    // -----------------------------
    private static final String REALM_TAG = "__REALM__";

    public static Realm getRealm(Context context) {
        // noinspection ResourceType
        return (Realm)context.getSystemService(REALM_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSystemService(@NonNull String name) {
        if(REALM_TAG.equals(name)) {
            return realm;
        }
        return super.getSystemService(name);
    }
}
```

Then in fragment you can do

```
Realm realm = MyActivity.getRealm(getActivity());
```

And in views you can do

```
Realm realm = MyActivity.getRealm(getContext());
```

---

2.) manage the Realm lifecycle globally for the UI thread using retained fragment as lifecycle listener / activity reference counter.

```
/**
 * Created by Zhuinden on 2016.08.16..
 */
public class RealmManager {
    private static final String TAG = "RealmManager";

    static Realm realm;

    static RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        Realm.init(context);
    }

    public static void initializeRealmConfig(Context appContext) {
        if(realmConfiguration == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Realm configuration.");
            setRealmConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(appContext).initialData(new RealmInitialData())
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .inMemory()
                    .build());
        }
    }

    public static void setRealmConfiguration(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration) {
        RealmManager.realmConfiguration = realmConfiguration;
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }

    private static int activityCount = 0;

    public static Realm getRealm() { // use on UI thread only!
        return realm;
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        if(activityCount == 0) {
            if(realm != null) {
                if(!realm.isClosed()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected open Realm found.");
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing Activity Count [0]: opening Realm.");
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
        activityCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Increment: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
    }

    public static void decrementCount() {
        activityCount--;
        Log.d(TAG, "Decrement: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
        if(activityCount <= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Decrementing Activity Count: closing Realm.");
            activityCount = 0;
            realm.close();
            if(Realm.compactRealm(realmConfiguration)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Realm compacted successfully.");
            }
            realm = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In conjunction with

```
public class RealmScopeListener
        extends Fragment {
    public RealmScopeListener() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        RealmManager.incrementCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        RealmManager.decrementCount();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And

```
/**
 * Created by Zhuinden on 2016.09.04..
 */
public class RealmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RealmManager.init(this);
        RealmManager.initializeRealmConfig(getApplicationContext());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RealmScopeListener realmScopeListener = (RealmScopeListener)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SCOPE_LISTENER");
        if(realmScopeListener == null) {
            realmScopeListener = new RealmScopeListener();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(realmScopeListener, "SCOPE_LISTENER").commit();
        }
        realm = RealmManager.getRealm();
    }
}
```

This allows you to call `RealmManager.getRealm()` **for the UI thread**, and its lifecycle is managed by retain fragments.

Comment: Is it safe to use RealmManager.getRealm() in a Service which doesn't start a background thread ?

Comment: Hmmm.... Considering the Realm instance is closed in my case when activities are closed and Services outlive the activity, I'll vote for no. You should probably open and close the Realm yourself there.

Comment: Ok this confirms what I thought, I'm also wondering if onDestroy is called in every case and if it's safe to decrement realm instance count there ?

Comment: The only time that is not called is if the process is terminated by android by low memory condition OR if the task is cleared, but it's the UI thread's Realm so even if it's not closed, you'll just be unable to delete or compact it in that process lifetime. Closing Realm is primarily essential for non-looping threads, so in my experience it seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm faced with a new problem, when I call finish() in the activity, the retained fragment is destroyed before the nested fragment, then when the nested fragment call realm.removeChangeListener() in onDestroyView I'm getting an exception because the realm instance is already closed. Do you have an idea to prevent this case ?

Comment: I tend to do a `if(realm.isClosed())` check that's all (I haven't had nested fragments though when I was using Realm so I hadn't run into this issue, sorry :/) another option is to just ditch the retained fragment and rely on `isFinishing()` after super.onDestroy(), and preserve realm with `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` across config change