# Using Java Realm in a single activity application?

Tags: java, android, realm

My app uses `Realm.getDefaultInstance` to open a Realm instance 30 times. I am closing the realm as much, but still having trouble finding the leak which causes the app device storage to balloon up.

I use just one "god activity" and many fragments, mostly dialogs. The implementation of Realm is messy, from about two years ago and in need of a refactor. Before I go through and replace the poor implementation (creating instance, doing whatever with results, then closing realm: no `try` or any other recommended implementation) I am wondering if it's possible to **have an instance just simply opened in `onCreate()` of the god activity and closed `onDestroy()` / `onStop()` instead of having many different instances** (one in each `DialogFragment` for example?

Comment: Yes, *except* if you're operating with it on a background thread there as well. Threads require their own thread-local instances. `try(Realm realm = ...)` is recommended.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce your response here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331742/how-to-manage-realm-instance ) has solved my problem, please submit an answer.